# php simple html dom parse a tag except in some div

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

some test get `a` tag from `http://www.msnbc.msn.com/` use simple html dom.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.msnbc.msn.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
$htmls = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$html = str_get_html($htmls);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){ 
    echo $element.'<br />';
}
```

this code could get all the hyper links, but how to ignore all the links in `div#mainNav`? I need get all the links out of `div#mainNav` in `http://www.msnbc.msn.com/`, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the parent, like this:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){ 
    if ($element->parent()->id == 'mainNav') {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        echo $element.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the links in `mainNav` or do you want the links outside of `mainNav` ?

Comment: I want outside of mainNav, but I still can get all the page links in my test.

Comment: Are the links direct descendents of mainNav? `parent()` gets the immediate parent. I recommend you do a `var_dump()` of `$element->parent()` and see what it shows you.

Comment: I know why not, because $element->parent() == 'li',$element->parent()->parent()== 'ul', $element->parent()->parent()->parent()== '#mainNav', so any other better suggestion? thanks.

Comment: I think that might be your best choice. Change the if condition to call `parent()` three times if `($element->parent()->parent()->parent()->id == 'mainNav') {`

Comment: i know, but this is more complex, I try to find some easy way, maybe I should do some regex after `$html = str_get_html($htmls)` then do `foreach($html->find('a') as $element){`

Comment: Another options would be to make an array of all anchors, then make an array of all anchors within `mainNav` and then do `array_diff`